# Drawer Layout in fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, drawerlayout

I tried to implement a Drawer Layout in a fragment, however, if I use "android: layout_gravity="start" then my navigational just disappears.The same code works fine if I put it in an activity. 
And if I try to swipe to the right, it also does not work (you can see it in the image I posted). For me, it looks like I can not swipe to the right and therefor the navigation view can not be opened?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="200dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation">
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[Image (if I swipe to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAnxR.png)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/eirabben/46d81bd9db52325563c7), you should add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the `DrawerLayout` and set its width to `match_parent`. My guess is, it should be the child `NavigationView` which can have a defined width.